# Postgres CLUSTER on JSONB GIN index?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, clustered-index

I'm trying to evaluate using Postgres with one JSONB column vs a more traditional relational model (each fields being one column). I recently found that CLUSTERing on an index in the relational model (in this case an index on one column) helped read performance a lot, understandably.

From my understanding, running CLUSTER  ON  will actually reorder how the table is stored physically, based on the index specified. What I was hoping to know is, if I run CLUSTER  ON , how exactly will the table be reordered? Is there any way to know before I actually execute the command, or is this more of a try-it-and-see scenarios?

If it's helpful, we are using the jsonb_path_ops operator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can cluster on a GIN index because there is no natural ordering in the index.  Clustering physically reorders on the order of the index and gin indexes don't have an ordering on them per se.

So I would be extremely surprised if this worked.  I think you would need a btree index instead.

Now, you could do a functional index on an attribute of the jsonb and cluster on that, I think.

Comment: Yup, you're right, I worked up the courage to just do it and got this:

"ERROR:  cannot cluster on index "<GIN index>" because access method does not support clustering".

I didn't want to run it just in case it would go through and end up reordering the data without a way to revert it, so I held off, but in hindsight I should've just tried it. Thanks!